# Was Stan Lee's cameo in Captain Marvel computer generated?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, stan-lee, captain-marvel

About half-way through *Captain Marvel* we see a cameo of the late Stan Lee.

Was this scene computer generated, or was it real?

Comment: I think we need a more Googleable title... but I can't think of one that wouldn't be a spoiler [except we all know he was in them all... so maybe it wouldn't be] Ideas??

Comment: When Marvel was taking off, they planned out the next ~20 movies, and then had Stan Lee film his parts for all of them, just in case.

Comment: @Tetsujin [Spoilers are allowed here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), after all, we are discussing the shows, plots, characters, etc., so _by all means_ what is your better title idea?

Comment: Is it a spoiler that Stan Lee had a cameo? That's been common for most (all?) the recent marvel movies.

Comment: I get the point about spoilers - I even said so in my initial comment... but if anyone posts "How did the Night King manage to kill John in S8E2?" one Monday morning before I've  seen that GoT, I'll moider 'em :P

Comment: I've edited the title to be more searchable, since it was already obvious from the title (even to someone like me who knows nothing about the MCU except through hanging out on Stack Exchange) that the question would be about a Stan Lee cameo.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The scene was for real - It was shot before Stan died, although they did make a small change after his passing:

From this [link](https://mashable.com/article/captain-marvel-stan-lee-cameo/?europe=true#4cBoGA1GPgqk)

> The Captain Marvel scene was originally written by directors Anna
>   Boden and Ryan Fleck as just another fun, funny appearance by the
>   comics legend. But after his passing in November, the filmmakers felt
>   compelled to update the sequence to acknowledge the "gravitas" of the
>   moment.
>
> "Instead of just the pure laugh we had, we had a little bit of a smile
>   from Captain Marvel in response to it, and she kind of breaks
>   character for a moment," Boden told me during an interview in Los
>   Angeles last month. "I think it reflects a little bit of what the
>   audience is feeling, and we allowed that to happen."

Having been to see it last night - both this cameo and the change to the intro sequence definitely made me smile!

Comment: He has 2 more cameo that were recorded before his passing

Comment: The reason this is my favorite Stan Lee cameo is that he's reading a script for the 1995 movie *Mallrats*, in which he appeared briefly. If you listen to him, you'll realize that in *this* cameo he's rehearsing his lines for *that* cameo!